# How to redirect file open call for binary

Tags: linux, bash

I have a binary `b` which tries to open `./a`. I would like run `b` multiple times, each time with different content in `a`. `b` is called by a framework which imposes the following limitations:

1. The multiple runs of `b` happen concurrently, which means they must not actually open the same file `a`, and I cannot change the content of `a` between runs
2. All instances of `b` are run in the same directory.
3. I cannot `cd` into different directories which contain a uniqe file named `a`
4. `b` itself cannot be modified to call a file other than `./a`.

Is there some way I can wrap `b` in such a way that when it tries to open `a` it will actually redirect to `some/other/dir/a`? Note that `b` is called from `bash`.

The only way I could think of is hooking the `open()` system-call, but would prefer something simpler.

Comment: Can you modify the binary `b`?

Comment: What do you mean by "different versions"? If the file is named `a` and is in a certain directory, there is only one unique file.

Comment: I cannot modify `b`, however I can wrap it. And I edited the question to make sense of the "different versions" part.

Comment: What file system are you using?

Comment: ect4 on ubuntu linux